# React-redux causing bundle error in reactnative

Tags: react-redux, redux-toolkit

ERROR  TypeError: 0, _redux.combineReducers is not a function (it is undefined), js engine: hermes
ERROR  Invariant Violation: "main" has not been registered. This can happen if:

- Metro (the local dev server) is run from the wrong folder. Check if Metro is running, stop it and restart it in the current project.
- A module failed to load due to an error and `AppRegistry.registerComponent` wasn't called., js engine: hermes

I was applying redux in my code. Suceessfuly made action and reducer file. But encounterd an error after creating store.js file.
I followed Code step by step tutorial and encountered error while performing lecture number 7.

----reducer------

```
import { ADD_TO_CART } from "../../constants";

const initialState=[]

export const reducer = (state=initialState,action) => {
    switch(action.type){
        case(ADD_TO_CART):
        return[
            ...state,
            action.data
        ]
        default:
            return state
    }
}
```

----root reducer-----

```
import { reducer } from "./reducer";
import { combineReducers } from "redux";

const rootreducer = combineReducers({
    reducer
}) 
export default rootreducer
```

-----store----

```
import rootreducer from "./rootreducer";
import { configureStore } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";

 const store = configureStore({
    reducer:rootreducer
})

export default store
```

-------app-----

```
import { StyleSheet, Text, View , Image, ScrollView, Button } from 'react-native';
import { SafeAreaView } from 'react-native-safe-area-context';

import Header from './components/Header';
import Product from './components/Product';
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import store from "./components/redux/store";

export default function App() {



  const products= [
    {
      name:"Hp Laptop",
      color:"Black",
      price:"64000",
      image:"https://media.gettyimages.com/id/104248569/photo/modern-laptop.jpg?s=612x612&w=0&k=20&c=Zxas4aHRO-iEgMVMnwXxmEiDdf55KUQrWFaWTTb5JVU="
    },
    {
      name:"Mac Book",
      color:"White",
      price:"164000",
      image:"https://l.hdnux.com/350x235p/hearst-images.s3.amazonaws.com/getty/article/176/143/113879440_XS.jpg"
    },
    {
      name:"Dell Laptop",
      color:"Grey",
      price:"54000",
      image:"https://c1.neweggimages.com/ProductImageCompressAll300/B295D211231147ZV9F0.jpg"
    },
  ]

  return (
    <Provider store={store}>
    <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
      <Header/>
      <ScrollView>
      {
        products.map((item, index)=>(
           <Product key={index} item={item}/>
           ))
      }
      </ScrollView>
    </SafeAreaView>
    </Provider>

  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    marginTop:10   
  },
});
```